# Percentage of power plants with carbon capture and sequestration (CCS) technology?

Tags: carbon

Does anyone know roughly what percentage of fossil fuel power plants around the world are equipped with [carbon capture and sequestration (CCS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_capture_and_storage) technology?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you accept [GE's estimate](http://files.gereports.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/ge-industrial-internet-vision-paper.pdf) of the number of global fossil fuel power plants ( 17,500 ) and compare it to the number of CCS projects out there ( 22 ), you get roughly 0.1 %.

The Global CCS Institute released its [2014 annual report](http://hub.globalccsinstitute.com/sites/default/files/publications/180923/global-status-ccs-2014.pdf);

> The world’s first large-scale carbon capture and storage (CCS) project in the power
>   sector commenced operation in October 2014 at the Boundary Dam power station
>   in Saskatchewan, Canada. Two additional large-scale CCS projects in the power
>   sector – at the Kemper County Energy Facility in Mississippi and the Petra Nova
>   Carbon Capture Project in Texas – are planned to come into operation in 2015 and
>   2016 respectively. Construction is also underway on the world’s first large-scale CCS
>   project in the iron and steel sector, the Abu Dhabi CCS Project in the United Arab
>   Emirates (UAE). These four projects are among the 22 large-scale CCS projects in
>   operation or construction around the world – double the number at the beginning of
>   the decade.

Comment: This is pathetically few! Most countries (and I'm ashamed to have to include Australia) are not taking CCS seriously, are investing orders of magnitude too little in the technology, and have a time line of CCS development which is laughably too slow to make any significant impact upon meaningful GHG emissions. Add to that the limited number of sites which are suitable for CO2 storage, and we are left with only one option to avoid disaster: Transition to anon-carbon economy - fast!

Comment: Actually you might like this article as an alternative: http://carbon.xprize.org/news/introducing-20m-nrg-cosia-carbon-xprize